# Is there a minimum amount of Zen that I should offer to buy on the dilithium exchange?

Tags: star-trek-online

I offered to buy ~20 Zen for 500 dilithium per zen on the exchange, but it hasn't been picked up yet. Is that because the exchange is now "broken" and exchanges take forever, or is it because I offered to small an exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zen purchases are made on a First-in-First-out basis ranked by value.  Too small an exchange offer will not delay your purchase, but too low a Dilithium-per-Zen value *would*.

Currently, the Zen exchange is at the Dilithium Cap; the system does not *permit* purchases to exceed 500 Dilithium per Zen (at the other end, it does not permit purchases to be *below* 25 Dilithium per Zen)

While there is lots that *could* be said for why that is the case, all arguments boil down to one thing: there are increasing numbers of desirable items that people can spend their Zen on, and no influx of desirable items to spend Dilithium on.

As such, there are **far** more people looking to *buy* Zen than there are looking to *sell* Zen.  This has resulted in a backlog of unfulfilled offers — your offer joined the back of the queue, and will be processed when offers ahead of you go through.  Offers to sell Zen are fulfilled near-instantly from that backlog of offers to buy Zen.

However, a small purchase might be *advantageous* here; **if** all offers ahead of you were for more than 20 Zen, and someone attempted to sell 20 Zen in exchange for 10,000 dilithium, then yours would be the first *actionable* purchase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. You've been extremely helpful in answering both my questions!